# Looking for a systematic approach to resolve a 403 error

Tags: routing, http-status-code-403, analysis

I wonder, how to tackle this strange problem.

#### Update 2

Using your comments and answers this seems to be the current situation:

- apparently constant over time
- variable with "location" (like geography, IP-ranges, devices, server, ...)

[image: update2]

The webhoster introduces changes from time to time, like the transition from http to https, and others.

While I myself didn't touch the parts of server configuration, which I could access, for over a year.

#### Update 1

From inspecting the errorlog, the file suggests a problem with the favicon.ico (sure ?)

> [Fri Nov 03 08:44:23.420596 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid
> 419198:tid 22878466176768] [remote 185.68.241.68:50959] AH01797:
> client denied by server configuration: /home ...
> /... /favicon.ico, referer:
> https://... .de/

From chat with support the current conclusions are:

- Supp: here the isue is the website is not accessible from one region
- Me: my ISP has means to enable or disable regional access?
- Supp: yes, since the access is blocked locally
- Supp: you can mention that website is not accessible  from your IP and accessible everywhere else in the world

As it's late Friday now in my place, I'll have to wait until Monday to talk to my Internet Service Provider.

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

#### Situation

I run a domain and a subdomain on a web-hoster in the US. I can access my domain, but not my subdomain:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The situation is as depicted:

- I ... can't access it (red) // 1 desktop, 1 tablet, 4 browsers in total
- support in USA can access it (green) // including his mobile phone
- my local Internet provider can't either (red)
- somebody in a different German city can't (red)
- while somebody else in just another different city can (green)

However, it's not clear how trustworthy some feedbacks are.

[image: situation]

#### Hypotheses

I see two possible explanations:

1. my server config isn't ok any more (they recently silently switched from http to https, and more)
2. some server on the routes falsely interacts, triggering a 403

#### My question

How to analyse this situation systematically?

E.g. I was pondering asking several people to:

- try to access both sites (does the problem really vary?)
- send me a tracert result (do some servers, i.e. frequently used ones, on the route possibly interact?)

Perhaps there are some helpful tools around, I simply don't know?

Answer (score 3):

## A systematic approach to investigating 403 errors

1. Read the [manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

> HTTP 403 is an HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden. The server understood the request, but will not fulfil it, if it was correct.

Of course that [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) tells a lot more but one of the things to take away is that and:

A HTTP 403 error is **server response** is **generated by the web-server**.

As a sysadmin you should already know that most web servers will log for every error a message describing  WHY they generated that error.

The next step for a server administrator is therefore:

### Look at the server error log.

If/when there is no (error) log: (re-) configure the webserver to start logging errors.

Then:

### Read the 403 error message in the log

and decide if there is an issue to address, or if the reason why access was denied is valid and the error is desired behaviour.

---

Things to consider: clients may be resolving your site name with either IPv4 or IPv6 and those protocols may be handled differently by your server or server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder and hint. All I now need to do is to find out, where they hid and burried the logfiles ...

Comment: Assuming the report I depicted is correct and trustworthy: how does it fit with your remarks?

Comment: Referring to my update, your remarks seem to be both right and wrong.

Comment: The `AH01797: client denied by server configuration:` says it all. You’re running Apache httpd and something in either the main `httpd.conf` or an included configuration snippet (pulled in the main httpd.conf with either `Include` and/or `IncludeOptional`) OR a `.htaccess` file is to blame. The problem is for example not the result of incorrect file system permissions

Comment: Thank you, that's valuable to me. However, with "Update 2" above in mind, I don't see, how this explains my current observations. // Here is a suggestion wrt IPV4/IPV6: https://serverfault.com/questions/1147162/verification-can-an-isp-limit-regional-access-to-a-website

Comment: The answer you accepted in your other question is an answer to the literal question "*Can an ISP limit regional access to a website?"*, which is indeed yes, but half or more of the possibilities in that answer WILL NOT RESULT IN **YOUR WEBSERVER** generating a 403 error response. The root of such an error is still: your webserver configuration denies access, that's why the site visitor sees a 403. When attempting to direct the site visitor to a friendly error page - a second error is triggered, because access to that error page is also denied.

Comment: You still haven't looked for or shown evidence to the friendly people attempting to answer your questions: how you have configured your web server in other words: the VirtualHost and/or `.htaccess` configuration. If you're not managing your web server, reach out to whomever does. But the assumption on ServerFault is that you do have admin access to the systems you're asking about. When you're only managing content, you are probably still responsible for `.htaccess` files (which are a common place to add access restrictions) and a misconfiguration there can also result in access getting blocked

Comment: Sorry to make you angry. // My access is limited to what cpanel allows you to see or to change. // My last changes on that level are over a year ago and everything was fine. //  `.htaccess` over the years are sometimes changed by the hoster, not by me. The actual one has unchanged content wrt the time my last access worked. // I agree on the hosters involvement. However, you should get how difficult that communication is. Just think about their argument, my Internet Service Provider must be the problem. // If you haven't noticed, I do appreciate the knowledge shared with me here.