# Verification: can an ISP limit regional access to a website?

Tags: https, http, isp

As I lined out [here on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1147140/looking-for-a-systematic-approach-to-resolve-a-403-error) my web-hosters support claims the following:

- because they can access my subdomain from the US
- while from Germany it resolves to a 403 error
- it must me my Internet Service Provider, limiting regional access (i.e. claiming it's not their fault).

I just wonder, hence want to verify, how, by which technology, an ISP can allow to load a website in certain parts of the world, while in other parts browsers/clients receive a 403 error.

If you want to try yourself:

- domain is OK: https://www.ms-spo.de
- subdomain 403: https://suprion-verlag.ms-spo.de

Comment: Your domain could have an IPV4 and an IPV6 address, with only one of them configured correctly, so depending on whether your provider supports IPV6 (which could depend on which part of the world you're in) you may be able to access it. This is not the case with your domains (no IPV6 AAAA entry present). Also, it seems like the cache expiry time for your domains is 14400 seconds (4 hours) so, after a DNS change, it can take up to 4 hours until "everybody" notices the change. Both of these can explain "it works from some places, but not from everywhere".

Comment: Thank you, that are interesting aspects. Must have a look, how to check or configure this via cpanel.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, may be a silly question from an inexperienced. I see a ZoneEditor, which holds my main domain, but not my subdomain. Would adding the subdomain there resolve the access-problem? (If so, this may have been forgotten by the hosters admin scripts) // Which lower value would you recommand for TTL? Thank you

Comment: I am in Germany, and https://suprion-verlag.ms-spo.de works for me, so, if it still doesn't work for you, something strange is going on. The DNS records look ok to me, both pointing to `162.241.24.95`. I have zilch experience with cpanel or its zone editor,  but as DNS looks ok, you probably don't need to change anything there.
As to the TTL, I typically set it to 86400 during normal operation, reduce to 300 two or three days before an anticipated change, and increase to 86400 again when I'm done.

Comment: What you could do to debug is run `nslookup suprion-verlag.ms-spo.de`, `nslookup suprion-verlag.ms-spo.de ns1.bluehost.com` and `nslookup suprion-verlag.ms-spo.de ns2.bluehost.com` and check if any of them does *not* return 162.241.24.95. And, on a second thought, make sure you don't have geofencing enabled anywhere; geofencing plus an outdated ip database could lead to exactly your problem.

Comment: Thank you @GuntramBlohm, very good remarks. Tried nslookup earlier today on MS-DOS, will repeat on Linux later. 162.241.24.95 was returned with your first call; the others I have to try. // Geofencing: I'm not aware, I can even activate it. Thanks

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, all nslookups do resolve to said IP. However, I'm better prepared now for an other support chat with my hoster ... // I assume you mean an ip database related to geofencing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ISPs use transit providers to route traffic to different parts of the world. So a transit provider is Asia can block a certain site while a transit provider in Europe might allow it. An transit provider is a provider who has a presence on a internet exchange and thus can route traffic to the datacenters in that region
They could block using a DNSBL like unbound does it. Or null route the IP. Some ISPs like Verizon, are also transit providers for other ISPs.

Comment: Thank you. Almost in parallel I added both URL's to my question. Still puzzled why the domain should be working, while the subdomain shouldn't, following the regional-argument.

Answer (score 7):

Tell your host to stick it.

suprion-verlag.ms-spo.de presents a valid Let's Encrypt certificate. *They* return a 403; not some ISP in the path. DNS returns the same for both domains you list.

This is misconfiguration on your hosts side, but it's impossible for us to assist with. Since they appear to be idiots, my best suggestion would be to change host.

Comment: Thank you for spelling out my thoughts ... Will have a closer look at their webinterface, which changed once again to dig out some innocent flag set or forgotten to set ... or so ...